# How do I disable the slide animation when deleting emails in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, remote-desktop, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2010

I work remotely fairly frequently, and I'm constantly irritated by the delete email animation in Outlook 2007. Over Remote Desktop Connection this can take a frustrating amount of time when you're trying to blast through your mails!

Any idea how to disable it? Any idea if you can in Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 3):

There's a setting in Outlook 2010 that takes some of the pain away: "Don't automatically expand conversations when using the keyboard to change messages". It's not a solution to your problem; I wish there was one that I knew of. Maybe someone will come forward with one.

This setting helps a bit for me by lessening the amount of slide up/down animations that you see in Conversation view.

Comment: Will give that a go when I eventually upgrade. Have a +1 for a small step in the right direction :)

Comment: ooh thanks. BTW this is buried under Options->Advanced settings. The very last checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the way the window sort of swoops and fades away quickly?  That's part of Windows Aero - not Outlook.

If you right click the Outlook shortcut icon and go to Properties and then the Compatibility tab, you can turn off Desktop Composition.  This will turn Aero off whenever you are running Outlook.

Comment: No - I mean the animation you get in Outlook when you delete mails, and the mails below the deletion point all slide up to fill in the space. Also, this is on Windows XP, so not Aero related.

Comment: I spent the last hour to find out how to **enable** smooth scrolling because my Outlook 2007 doesn't do it :-) !

Comment: @karatedog - You can have mine if you want ;)